# Listen for changes rxswift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am using deeplink to open my application so if the a button is tapped, the user gets an email in turn clicks the link and is directed to the same page he/she is currently. I am using the MVVM architecture and I want to be able to make changes based on result got from an api call which occurs when the user gets back to the App but I am unable to get my Observables to react from the Api response

```
init(routeManager: RouteMatchResult?, provider: Api, currentEmail: String?) {
        self.routeManager = BehaviorRelay(value: routeManager)
        self.currentEmail = BehaviorRelay(value: currentEmail)
        nightModeEnabled = BehaviorRelay(value: ThemeType.currentTheme().isDark)
        super.init(provider: provider)
        self.dataXXX.accept(())
//        loadInvite()
    }

    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {

dataXXX.asObservable().subscribe({_ in
            print("DDDD=========++++++++++++==========DDDDD")
        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
       return Output()
}
```

However, if I uncomment `loadInvite()` the code runs in that function and trying to get `dataXXX` to subscribe to does not work

```
func loadInvite() {

        routeManager.errorOnNil().asObservable()

            .flatMapLatest { (code) -> Observable<RxSwift.Event<User>> in
            log("=========++++++++++++==========")
//            guard let code = code else {return}
            let params = code.values

            return self.provider.postVerifyApp(challengeId: code)
            .trackActivity(self.loading)
            .trackError(self.error)
            .materialize()
        }.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (event) in
            log("=========++++++++++++==========+++++++++++", .fuck)
            switch event {
            case .next(let token):
                log(token)
                if token.data != nil {
                    self?.dataStatuBool.accept(true)
                    self?.dataStatus.onNext(true)
                    log("=========++++++++++ TRUE ========+++++++++++", .fuck)
                    self?.homeData.onNext(())
                } else {
                    self?.nilData.onNext(())
                    self?.dataStatuBool.accept(false)
                    self?.dataStatus.onNext(false)
                    log("=========+++++++++ FALSE ======+++++++++++", .fuck)
                }
            case .error(let error):
                log(error.localizedDescription)
            default: break
            }
        }).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)

        nilData.asObservable().flatMapLatest { () -> Observable<EmailSharingViewModel> in
            print("SUBBBBBBB XXX")
            let viewModel = EmailSharingViewModel(provider: self.provider)
            return Observable.just(viewModel)
        }.subscribe()
        .disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue here is when you do `self.dataXXX.accept(())` your observable isn't subscribed yet. Usually, in an MVVM architecture your subscriptions should happen in viewDidLoad() in view controller instead of view model, view model only in charge of composing and exposing all observables you need and subscribe them in a view controller.

Check the example here: https://github.com/uptechteam/Coordinator-MVVM-Rx-Example/tree/master/MVVM-Rx/RepoSearcher/Classes/RepositoryList